# Why do the \| characters in an :execute "normal ..." mapping require extra escaping backslashes?

Tags: key-bindings, regular-expression

I'm struggling to understand a character escaping situation involving `\|`.

First I'm running the following search which matches either the `A` character or `B` character.  I'm using the default `magic` option so the parentheses `()` and alternatives separator `|` must be preceded by backslashes:

```
/\(A\|B\)
```

Next I'd like to execute this as a `normal` command, so I run the following command and it works as expected.  Since the search expression is now in a double quoted string, I have to escape each backslash character:

```
:execute "normal! /\\(A\\|B\\)\r"
```

Finally I'd like to create a normal mode mapping which executes this command.  I run the following command:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>h :<C-u>execute "normal! /\\(A\\|B\\)\r"<CR>
```

However, when attempting to use this mapping, I get the following error:

```
E486: Pattern not found: \(A|B\)
```

In order to get this mapping to work, I have to add an additional backslash before the `|` character, but I don't have to add additional backslashes before the `(` or `)` characters!  The working command is as follows:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>h :<C-u>execute "normal! /\\(A\\\|B\\)\r"<CR>
                                                 ^
                                                 |
                                   three backslashes instead of two
```

Why is an extra backslash required here to make this work?  And why do the parentheses each not also require an extra backslash?

I'm running Vim 8.0, patches 1-1453, compiled myself on WSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|` is used to separate a map command from the next one, you need to escape it or use `<bar>` instead, read [:h map-bar](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#map-bar) for further detail.

Your map is unnecessarily complicated, `{rhs}` of a `map` without [:h :map-<expr>](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-%3Cexpr%3E) is applied as typed, no need to use `execute` and `normal` in this case:

```
nnoremap <Leader>h /\(A\<bar>B\)<cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess, but I suspect it has to with `|` also being the ex command separator. So execute probably mangles things, and needs to see `\|`, which in string form would `\\\|`—in other words, `|` needs to be escaped.

Alternative ideas:

1. `:/` is an ex command that addresses the search pattern entered. If memory serves, it works rather like a normal `/`
2. You can also set the search register with `let @/ = ...` and then simply `:normal! n`

Comment: `:/` and `/` is different, see [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21975/whats-the-difference-between-x-and-x)