# What's the difference between `/x` and `:/x`

Tags: vimscript, search

Assume buffer content:

```
aa bb
yy xx
aa bb
```

What's the different between `/xx` and `:/xx`?

Comment: I was discussing this with BLayer in another question, he think it's bad to hijack that question, so i open this question.

Comment: Yeah, I felt bad as it was a first time poster and there was a wall of mostly off-topic comments distracting from the question. Anyways, it looks like you uncovered an extra layer of nuance to this. I'll take a closer look when I get back later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`/xx` place cursor at `xx`, it's a [:h /](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F) .

`:/xx` is a [:h :[range]](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%3A%5Brange%5D) , not [:h :range](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Arange) , it's a valid ex command by itself, it's behavior is affected by [:h 'startofline'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27startofline%27) .

If `'startofline'` is on (default), `:/xx` place cursor at 1st non-blank of the line that contain `xx`, it's the leading `y` in this case.

If `'startofline'` is off, `:/xx` move cursor to the matching line without moving the column if possible (you have to move the column if target line is too short).