# Jump to a specific line without moving the cursor horizontally

Tags: cursor-movement

Consider you are editing the left table in Vim.  Your cursor (■) is at Line 14, Column 12.

```
Where you are now          Move the cursor

11 +-------+-----+         11 +-------+-----+
12 | Name  | Age |         12 | Name  | Age |
13 +=======+=====+         13 +=======+=====+
14 | Alice | 5■  |   -->   14 | Alice | 5   |
15 +-------+-----+         15 +-------+-----+
   ...                        ...
95 +-------+-----+         95 +-------+-----+
96 | Zoe   |     |         96 | Zoe   |  ■  |
97 +-------+-----+         97 +-------+-----+
```

What's the easy way to move your cursor at Line 96, Column 12, i.e., jump to this specific line without moving horizontally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn off [:h 'startofline'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27startofline%27) :

```
set nostartofline
```

And execute one of the following command:

```
96G
:96
:/Zoe
```

It will place cursor at target line without moving horizontally if target line is longer enough.

Commands starts with `:` are ex command, check this [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21975/whats-the-difference-between-x-and-x) if you are confused about `/` and `:/` .

Comment: Confirmed. I already like this behavior so much that I have added `set nostartofline` to my .vimrc to enable this by default, globally.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 96th line actually has column no. 12 (or `set virtualedit=all`), you can do `96zz` (or `96zt`, or `96zb`).

See `:h scroll-cursor` for more information.

Comment: `zz`, `zt` and `zb` work but they also scroll the window which is confusing.. Any way not to scroll/redraw the window?

Comment: @Culip Is `84j` okay?

Comment: In this case I have to use relative line numbers or do the math (line 96 - 14). Um..